# extracting first and last positions in a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset that I'm trying to transform to get the "from" and "to" positions within a particular grouping of data points that pass a test.

Here's how the data looks:

```
pos <- seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10)
test <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(pos, test)
```

So you can see that positions 10, 20, and 30, as well as 70, 80, and 90 pass the test (b/c test = 1) but the rest of the points don't. The answer I'm looking for would be a data frame that looks something like the "answer" data frame in the code below:

```
peaknum <- c(1, 2)
from <- c(10, 70)
to <- c(30, 90)
answer <- data.frame(peaknum, from, to)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can transform the dataset? I'm stumped.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Use the `rleid` function to create the run-length group ids ('peaknum') based on the adjacent values that are same 'test'.  Using 'peaknum' as grouping variable, we get the 'min' and 'max' of 'pos', while specifying the 'i' as 'test==1' to subset the rows.  If needed, the 'peaknum' values can be changed to the sequence ('seq_len(.N)`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, peaknum:= rleid(test)][test==1, 
   list(from=min(pos), to=max(pos)) ,peaknum][, peaknum:= seq_len(.N)]
#   peaknum from to
#1:       1   10 30
#2:       2   70 90
```

Comment: That worked absolutely beautifully. It makes me think I should learn data.table at some point :-)

Comment: @Steven, you'll know if it's for you or not by spending ~10-15 mins on the [Introduction to data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette.

Answer (score 3):

We can do it with `dplyr`, though separating the nodes is a little ugly:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(peaknum = rep(seq(rle(test)[['lengths']]), rle(test)[['lengths']])) %>% 
  filter(test == 1) %>% 
  summarise(from = min(pos), 
            to = max(pos)) %>%
  mutate(peaknum = seq_along(peaknum))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

#   peaknum  from    to
#     (int) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1       1    10    30
# 2       2    70    90
```

What it does:

- the first `group_by` uses `rle` to add a column that is a sequence along the repeated numbers in `test`, and groups it for `summarise` later;
- `filter` chops rows down to only those where `test` is `1`
- `summarise` collapses the groups and adds `max` and `min` for each,
- and lastly `mutate` cleans up the numbering of `peaknum`.

Comment: Or load data.table alongside dplyr and use rleid for the first step.

Comment: Yeah, that would make it a lot prettier.